# Format exception was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

```
@foreach (var result in Model)
      {              
        ////var num=Convert.ToInt32(x);
        //int n=int.Parse(x);
        //int n=Integer.parseInt(x);            
      if (Convert.ToInt64(@result.Difference) < 0)
      {
      <tr>
        <td>@result.SalesIncentiveBuckets
        </td>
        <td>@result.CurrentMonth
        </td>
        <td>@result.SameMonthPrevYear
        </td>
        <td style="color:Red;">@result.Difference
        </td> 
        <td>@result.BonusAmount
        </td>
      </tr>
      }
      else
      {
      <tr>
         <td>@result.SalesIncentiveBuckets
         </td>
         <td>@result.CurrentMonth
         </td>
         <td>@result.SameMonthPrevYear
         </td>
         <td>@result.Difference
         </td> 
         <td>@result.BonusAmount
         </td>
       </tr>
      }
    }
```

In my model difference is a string, and I want to convert it into integerI tried in all the ways I could, but it is showing this error:

> input string not in a correct format

Comment: What's the value of Difference?

Comment: "33,64,559" is the value of difference.

Answer (score 0):

It's the *commas* in the string causing this exception, Try this

```
int num = int.Parse(result.Difference, NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

You have to add `System.Globalization` namespace to achieve this.

Comment: its not working need to add any refernce for getting numberstyles